# Creating a list of 5 high scores with player names in unity, using playerprefes and input field for playername

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game wherein the beginning the user puts his name in the input field. This is in a different scene. I want to be able to display the 5 highest scores corresponding to the name of the player who got that score.
I am specifically struggling with how to actually display the high score system I have built and link it with the name.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI HighScoreTmp;

    public string theName;
    public GameObject InputField;
    public GameObject TextDisplay;

    List<int> scores;
    List<string> names;

    public void Start()
    {

        scores = new List<int>();
        names = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            scores.Add(0);
            names.Add("xxx");
        }

        loadHighScore();
    }

    /*public void StoreName()
    {
        theName = InputField.GetComponent<Text>().text;
        //TextDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Hi!" + theName + "ready to play?";
    }*/

    public void storeHighScores()
    {
        theName = InputField.GetComponent<Text>().text; //storing name for later

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score" + i, scores[i]);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("name" + i, names[i]);

        }

        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    public void loadHighScore()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("score" + i))
            {
                scores[i] = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score" + i);
                names[i] = PlayerPrefs.GetString("name" + i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addHighScore(string name,int value)
    {
        bool inserted = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5 && !inserted; i++)
        {
            if (value > scores [i])
            {
                scores.Insert(i, value);
                names.Insert(i, name);
            }
        }

        if (scores.Count > 5)
        {
            scores.RemoveAt(5);
            names.RemoveAt(5);
        }

        storeHighScores();
    }

    public void fillInHighScore()
    {
        //make a tmp for name and score with a loop for each name and score

         HighScoreTmp.text = "list of  5 highscores"; //+ PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);

        //HighScoreTmp.text = "HighScore" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);
    }

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("StartSceneClass");
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        GameManagerPro.Instance.CalculateScore();

        Debug.Log("quiting game");

        Application.Quit();
    }

    public void HauptMenu()
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading menu..");

        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I have a hard time figuring out what exactly your question is .. what exactly does not behave as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

It's not what is not behaving as expected but I cannot figure out how to display the high score together with the names in my UI. The method fillInHighScore is where I should do this but I am very unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Use this OnCollisionEnter function to add 1 to the score accumulation if the object collides. For example, void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){} writes out the instantiated object, Score.x += 1; Score.txt.text = "Score : " + Score. x;

Comment: You would probably simply spawn multiple `Text` / `TextMeshPro` prefabs into a container that is e.g. using a [`VerticalLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html) and assign the text to each of them in a loop ...